# force block module to load admin panel theme

Tags: 6, blocks, theming

I use diffident themes for admin panel and content pages. when I want to use block module, it loads my content page theme (made by me) and doesn't work correctly.

how can I force block module to display admin panel theme?

or maybe force it to display a specific theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are asking is if, when you go to `admin/build/block`, is there a way to make drupal use your admin theme instead of your custom theme, then the answer to that question is no, because it needs your theme to figure out what regions are available and what blocks are in them.  But it will allow you to pick different active themes so you can put different blocks in different regions in different themes if desired once your custom theme has the needed regions and other logic required to work with the block admin pages.

Comment: Thanks, well somehow block module determines whats the custom theme , isn't there any way to use some other theme?

Comment: if that custom theme is your system's default theme, it will use that first.  then it will include tabs for all the other active themes.

Comment: Thanks Jimajamma. I was looking for some modification in sources.